# How to interact between 32bit and 64bit applications

Tags: matlab, 32bit-64bit

I am developing and application in Matlab which relies on external 32bit libraries for a specific task which is frequently called and requires fast response. These libraries are only available in 32bit.
Since recent Matlab versions are only 64bit, I need to keep the development of the whole application in an outdated version of Matlab. I am looking for ways to overcome this limitation, and had two in mind.

First, I checked for ways to call the 32bit libraries from 64bit Matlab, but I was told this is either not possible or requires complex interface developments which I cannot assume.

Then I thought of splitting my application in two, one in 32bit Matlab that uses the 32 libraries and the other for all the rest of the functionalities in 64bit Matlab. I need to share data between them, just a few numbers, but it happens often and I need fast response (<1second).

I have tried to use a text file where both applications read and write. The main application would change a number there, and the other application would be continuously (every 0.1 sec for example) checking this value in the text file to know when it should start.

This solution works, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it, at least to avoid so frequent access to a text file on the hard drive, which can limit performance of the machine and even affect durability. Maybe something that is only stored in RAM?

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always create a virtual drive in your RAM, and store the file there. This way you gain speed, save your HDD, and store things in RAM like you wanted. Look for "ramdisk" or "ramdrive".

Comment: What OS are you using? Solutions for inter-program communication differ greatly between Windows and real OSes.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 or 10, forgot to mention. Thanks for the ramdisk suggestion, I was looking for something simpler anyway, which would not require system changes, that could be configured from within Matlab, something on a local webserver maybe...

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to exchange data between two applications of different bitness is using named pipes. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590.

The pipe server calls the CreateNamedPipe API function. The client can open the pipe like any other file.